# iPhone Development - EXC_BAD_ACCESS error with no stack trace

Tags: cocoa-touch

Here's my case: I have a table view showing contacts. Add button in the navigation bar is used to load another view for data entry. This new view has images in table header, and each table cell has either a *UITextField* or a *UITextView*. When i press Cancel, the view is popped out and memory is released.

Here's my issue: When i open the "Add" interface, provide a value in any of the UITextField or UITextView, and press "Cancel" to to go back to the parent view, i get an *EXC_BAD_ACCESS* error. When i trace it, the "Add Controller" calls dealloc properly, but after the *[super dealloc]* when i press Continue, it throws this error. Just this, no trace, although i'm using *NSZombieEnabled.* When i run the code with Instruments, i don't get any error :(

I hope i'm clear in explaining the issue. Any pointers? Thanks.

Comment: The problem magically disappears when I remove [tableView release] from my "Add Contact" Controller class's dealloc method. But I should release the tableView object, right? Although I'm using nib file - and made tableView an `IBOutlet`.

Comment: No, you shouldn't.  The rule to remember is 'If you didn't explicitly alloc, copy or retain it, then you don't explicitly release it.'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most common cause of this error is when you release an object and some other mechanism tries to access/release/dealloc it later.

Whenever I get a report of an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error, my first recommendation is to step through the code to determine which line is causing it, and then to search for any explicit `[object release]` calls that reference that object. Comment them out one-by-one to find where you may have gone wrong (and, of course, make sure the object is properly released later).

If the line doesn't help you figure out which object(s) is/are causing the problem, start looking through your `[object release]` calls, and make sure you aren't releasing objects too many times by accident, or releasing objects you don't own.

This leads to a good general guideline regarding `release` in Objective-C:

> If you own an object (allocate or retain it), you release it. If you don't own it (came via convenience method or someone else allocated it), you don't release it.

(Via [Memory Management with Objective C / Cocoa / iPhone](http://memo.tv/memory_management_with_objective_c_cocoa_iphone), which also has some good tips.)

Answer (score 6):

Although this is most often a result of mismanaged memory, it can happen for other reasons (and be harder to debug than simply turning on `NSZombieEnabled`). For example, if you fail to supply the correct number of arguments to a format string (i.e. while debugging another problem with `NSLog`), you could end up with no stack trace even with all debugging arguments enabled. Luckily, you can use GDB within Xcode to [restore the stack trace to a previous state](http://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/weblog/2010/07/exc_bad_access_and_no_stack_tr.html).

In the GDB console you should see the instruction that crashed your program. Locate the last successful return instruction before the one that failed. It should look something like this:

```
je    0x986cef35 <objc_msgSend+117>
```

Note the hex value and execute the following in GDB:

```
set $eip = 0x986cef35
stepi
where
```

You should (hopefully) have a more informative stack trace now.

[Source](http://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/weblog/2010/07/exc_bad_access_and_no_stack_tr.html) (same as the link above)

Comment: The [link] (http://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/weblog/2010/07/exc_bad_access_and_no_stack_tr.html) is not working. Here is the [updated] (http://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/weblog/2010/exc_bad_access_and_no_stack_tr.html) one

Answer (score 5):

Cameron Spickert's answer is a little deprecated, since Xcode uses lldb now instead of gdb. The link to the source article is also dead.

The same thing can be done rather simply with the following lldb command:

```
(lldb) thread backtrace
```

This will show the bt for the current thread. If you want to change the thread from which you want to get the bt, select the frame and get it like this:

```
(lldb) thread list
(lldb) thread select 2
(lldb) thread backtrace
```

If you want to replicate the exact behavior of Cameron Spickert's answer, use the following commands:

```
(lldb) expr unsigned int $eip = 0x1979c81d4
(lldb) stepi
(lldb) thread backtrace
```

[Source 1](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/gdb_to_lldb_transition_guide/document/lldb-terminal-workflow-tutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012917-CH4-SW9)

[Source 2](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/gdb_to_lldb_transition_guide/document/lldb-command-examples.html)

Answer (score 3):

Put the [super dealloc] as the last statement of the class dealloc method. You'll get this behavior when you dealloc the super class first.

Answer (score 1):

The general rule of thumb is that anything you create, you need to manage (retain/release). Anything that comes out of a NIB, should generally not be released in code.

Answer (score 1):

The statements above that you should not release NIB objects are contradicted by Apple: see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmNibObjects.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004998-SW2), where it says that objects for which you have an outlet should be released in dealloc, and also that you should make sure to set the object reference to nil afterwards.

Disclaimer: I'm an iPhone programming newbie, though have been programming for a long time.