# Objective-C memory management problem

Tags: objective-c, memory, exc-bad-access

I'm getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error, and It's because of this part of code. Basically, I take an input and do some work on it.  After multiple inputs, it throws the error.  Am I doing something wrong with my memory here?  I'd post the rest of the code, but it's rather long -- and I think this may be where my problem lies (It's where Xcode points me, at least).

```
-(IBAction) findShows: (id) clicked
{  
    char urlChars[1000];
    [self getEventURL: urlChars];
    NSString * theUrl = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%s", urlChars];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theUrl]];
    int theLength = [data length];
    NSString *content = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];

    char eventData[[data length]];
    strcpy(eventData, [content UTF8String]);
    [self parseEventData: eventData dataLength: theLength];
    [whatIsShowing setStringValue:@"Showing events by this artist"];
}
```

Comment: When pasting code, please make sure you replace the tabs with spaces in future.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## When a crash occurs, there will be a backtrace.

Post it.

Either your program will break in the debugger, and the call stack will be in the debugger UI (or you can type 'bt

With that, the cause of the crash is often quite obvious.  Without that, we are left to critique the code.

So, here goes....

---

```
char urlChars[1000];
[self getEventURL: urlChars];
```

This is, at best, a security hole and, at worst, the source of your crash.   Any time you are going to copy bytes into a buffer, there should be some kind of way to (a) limit the # of bytes copied in (pass the length of the buffer) and (b) the # of bytes copied is returned (0 for failure or no bytes copied).

Given the above, what happens if there are 1042 bytes copied into `urlChars` by `getEventURL:`?  *boom*

```
NSString * theUrl = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%s", urlChars];
```

This is making some assumptions about `urlChars` that will lead to failure.  First, it assumes that `urlChars` is of a proper `%s` compatible encoding.  Secondly, it assumes that `urlChars` is NULL terminated (and didn't overflow the buffer).

Best to use one of the various NSString methods that create strings directly from the buffer of bytes using a particular encoding.  More precise and more efficient.

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theUrl]];
```

I hope this isn't on the main thread... 'cause it'll block if it is and that'll make your app unresponsive on slow/flaky networks.

```
int theLength = [data length];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];

char eventData[[data length]];
strcpy(eventData, [content UTF8String]);
```

This is about the least efficient possible way of doing this.   There is no need to create an `NSString` instance just to then turn it into a `(char *)`.  Just grab the `bytes` from the data directly.

Also -- are you sure that the data returned is NULL terminated?  If not, that `strcpy()` is gonna blow right past the end of your `eventData` buffer, corrupting the stack.

```
[self parseEventData: eventData dataLength: theLength];
[whatIsShowing setStringValue:@"Showing events by this artist"];
```

What kind of data are you parsing that you really want to parse the raw bytes?   In almost all cases, such data should be of some kind of structured type;  XML or, even, HTML.   If so, there is no need to drop down to parsing the raw bytes.   (Not that raw data is unheard of -- just odd).

Comment: Good critique.  If you want to know the cause of the crash, my money is on this line `NSString *content = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];`.  The bytes in the data will not be null terminated - or guaranteed to by UTF-8 as it happens.

Comment: Also, `[data length]` returns `NSUInteger`, not `int`.

Answer (score 1):

The bytes you get from `[content UTF8String]` could conceivably be different in number from the value of `[data length]`. Try using `strncpy()` instead and see if that still crashes. (It's also possible that `getEventURL:` sometimes fails to return a string in the format expected, but that's impossible to tell without the source to that method.)

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that the string contained in `urlChars` sometimes comes back non-NULL-terminated? You might want to try zeroing out the array, for example using `bzero`.

Additionally, there are a bunch of techniques for debugging `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. Since you're doing a lot of pure C string manipulation, the usual method of turning on `NSZombieEnabled` may or may not help you (though I recommend turning it on regardless). Another technique you can try is recovering a previous stack frame using GDB. See [my previous answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468575/iphone-development-exc-bad-access-error-with-no-stack-trace/4309265#4309265) if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the code is too complex. Do not resort to plain C arrays and strings unless you absolutely have to, they are harder to get right. (It’s no rocket science, but if you play with guns all the time, you *will* shoot yourself in the foot sooner or later.) Even if you insist on parsing plain C strings, isolate the code using the function interface:

```
// Callers have to mess with char*.
- (void) parseEventData: (char*) data {…}

// Callers can stay in the Objective-C land.
- (void) parseEventData: (NSString* or NSData*) data {
    char *unwrappedData = …;
    …
}
```

I’d certainly think twice before I used `strcpy` in my code. And I think you are leaking `theUrl` (although that should not cause `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` in this case). As for the bug itself, you might be hanging on parts of `urlChars` or `eventData` and when those stack-based variables disappear, you cause the segfault?